# Why do OAuth packages in ASP.NET depend on Owin, and how does anyone use OAuth without Owin in an ASP.net web API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, webapi

There are multiple ways to secure a rest service like Basic authentication,API Key Authentication but OAuth is the most preferred ,I am new to Asp.Net and no nothing about Owin ,I have created a web Api project and now i want to secure it with OAuth 2.0 ,but all packages depend on Owin like Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.Why do i actually need Owin to implement Oauth? Can't i simply implement OAuth in my project?

I am very new in Asp.net and my question may sound stupid but i am really confused and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Absolutely you can. You can setup a OAuth 2.0 authentication flow manually by writing all the code yourself. Owin comes with the inbuilt packages which follow the standard OAuth2.0 and OpenId Connect handshake mechanism. They are offering it so that developers don't have to write it themselves.

Comment: @TejSoft can you please explain how to implement OAuth with Owin in web api?what are those codes that we don't write and Owin does it for us as you mentioned.